# Terraform Module not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, terraform, provisioning, amazon-aurora

I am kind of struggling to understand how the modules in Terraform work. What I am trying to achieve is

```
|TERRAFORM
   |RDS
     |main.tf
     |variables.tf
     |terraform.tfvars
   |Modules
     |rds_cluster
        |main.tf
        |variables.tf
     |rds_instance
        |main.tf
        |variables.tf
     |rds_subnet
        |main.tf
        |variables.tf
```

My Modules are listed below

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aurora_cluster" {
  cluster_identifier           = "${var.name}"
  availability_zones           = ["${var.availability_zones}"]
  database_name                = "${var.name}"
  master_username              = "${var.admin_user}"
  master_password              = "${var.admin_password}"
  backup_retention_period      = "${var.retention_period}"
  preferred_backup_window      = "${var.backup_window}"
  preferred_maintenance_window = "${var.maintenance_window}"
  kms_key_id                   = "${var.kms_key_id}"
  final_snapshot_identifier    = "${var.name}-FS"
  skip_final_snapshot          = "${var.skip_final_snapshot}"
  apply_immediately            = "${var.apply_immediately}"
  vpc_security_group_ids          = ["${var.vpc_rds_security_group_id}"]
  port                            = "${var.port}"
  db_subnet_group_name            = "${var.db_subnet_group_name}"
  db_cluster_parameter_group_name = "${var.db_cluster_parameter_group_name}"
  engine                          = "${var.engine}"
  engine_version                  = "${var.engine_version}"

  tags {
    Name         = "${var.name}"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

I wrote a module one level up

```
module "rds_cluster" {
  source = "../modules/rds_cluster"


  availability_zones              = ["${var.availability_zones}"]
  admin_user                      = "${var.admin_user}"
  admin_password                  = "${var.admin_password}"
  backup_retention_period         = "${var.retention_period}"
  backup_window                   = "${var.backup_window}"
  maintenance_window              = "${var.maintenance_window}"
  kms_key_id                      = "${var.kms_key_id}"
  skip_final_snapshot             = "${var.skip_final_snapshot}"
  apply_immediately               = "${var.apply_immediately}"
  vpc_security_group_ids          = ["${var.vpc_rds_security_group_id}"]
  port                            = "${var.port}"
 # db_subnet_group_name            = "${module.rds_db_subnet.aurora_subnet_group.name}"
  db_cluster_parameter_group_name = "${var.db_cluster_parameter_group_name}"
  engine                          = "${var.engine}"
  engine_version                  = "${var.engine_version}"

}
```

same variables.tf kept inside the root modules & resource module

```
########################
## Variables
########################

variable "region" {
  description = "AWS region to deploy this instance"
  default     = "us-east-1"
}

variable "access_key" {
  description = "The AWS access key."
}

variable "secret_key" {
  description = "The AWS secret key."
}

variable "environment_name" {
  description = "The name of the environment"
}

variable "vpc_name" {
  description = "The name of the VPC that the RDS cluster will be created in"
}

variable "app_name" {
  description = "Name of the application"
  default     = ""
}



variable "availability_zones" {
  description = "A list of EC2 Availability Zones that instances in the DB cluster can be created in"
  default     = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1f"]
}

variable "admin_user" {
  description = "User Name for the admin user"
  default     = "admin"
}

variable "admin_password" {
  description = "Provide the password of the RDS Admin User"
}

variable "retention_period" {
  description = "No of days to retain the backup for"
  default     = "7"
}

variable "backup_window" {
  description = "The daily time range (in UTC) during which automated backups are created if they are enabled. Example: '09:46-10:16'. Must not overlap with maintenance_window"
  default     = "02:00-03:00"
}

variable "maintenance_window" {
  description = "The weekly time range during which system maintenance can occur, in (UTC) e.g. wed:04:00-wed:04:30"
  default     = "wed:04:00-wed:05:00"
}

variable "kms_key_id" {
  description = " The globally unique identifier for the key"
  default     = ""
}

variable "skip_final_snapshot" {
  description = "Determines whether a final DB snapshot is created before the DB cluster is deleted.  If true is specified, no DB snapshot is created. If false is specified, a DB snapshot is created"
  default     = "False"
}

variable "apply_immediately" {
  description = "Specifies whether any cluster modifications are applied immediately, or during the next maintenance window."
  default     = "False"
}

variable "vpc_rds_security_group_id" {
  description = "The name of the environment"
}

variable "port" {
  description = "The port on which the DB accepts connections"
  default     = "3306"
}

variable "db_cluster_parameter_group_name" {
  description = "Parameter group associated with this instance's DB Cluster"
}

variable "engine" {
  description = "Which Engine is used for RDS Cluster, Choose from []"
  default     = "aurora-mysql"
}

variable "engine_version" {
  description = "Which version of DB Engine to be used?"
  default     = "5.7.12"
}
```

I am kind of passing every parameter in my resource to the module as well. But I keep seeing below error

> module "db_cluster" : "backup_retention_period" is not a valid
>   argument

It's happening for almost every other field. Is it that I can't use modules for Aurora?

> Question :
>
> In my example, RDS is the root module. So if I declared
>   backup_retention_period       in my resource, I need to pass the same
>   to my root module as input. Declare the variable and add it to
>   variable.tf in the root module. Which is exactly what I am doing I
>   believe.

Comment: You need to define your input variables to the module with something like `variable "foo" {}`.

Comment: I do have the variable.tf inside the root module which contains those variables defined. I will update the file structure in my question.

Comment: Not according to the error message. You should post your full module though.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited my question and added the code

Comment: You still haven't posted the variable definition

Comment: Oh my bad, thought the modules will give the idea. The same variables.tf is also placed in resource module dir. I was confused after seeing this thread

Comment: You haven't defined `backup_retention_period` as the error says.

Comment: I was confused after reading this thread. https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds/issues/41

Comment: Error: module "rds_cluster": "vpc_security_group_ids" is not a valid argument. I get errors for every field. After reading that thread, I was wondering if that post was related to just that module or global. Correct me my understanding is wrong. I will edit the OP and add the question. So that it will help others. Appreciate your help. Will be great help if you could clarify. Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't defined that either. Read the error messages and then check if you defined the variable.

Comment: God... Thanks Man.. I think it made sense to me now. I was misunderstanding the variable declaration I guess, so let's say inside my root module if I have preferred_backup_window         = "${var.backup_window}" I should keep both preferred_backup_window and backup_window in my variables.tf in the root module? or rather make it  preferred_backup_window         = "${var.preferred_backup_window}" and declare my preferred_backup_window in tfvars ?